How can I use Gradle to build multiple versions of a jar with a changed variable?
I'm working on a Java project that will be distributed to multiple clients, but need to have the client name in a variable within the java code for use in logging and version checking.
Is there a way to have a list of options set in gradle that when running the build task will generate multiple jars, one for each of the options? Each jar will need the variable added to the archive name and a java variable in the main class changed to match.
As an example, if I've got ['Client A', 'Client B'] as a gradle array, I would need a project-client-a.jar with the variable MainClass.CLIENT = "Client A" and a separate jar with project-client-b.jar with MainClass.CLIENT = "Client B"
My instinct is to use the expand function to replace a value in a properties file bundled into the jar, but I'm unsure how to "loop" multiple artifacts and replacement mappings.

You probably need to do some clever scripting

While a pure Gradle solution is still preferred, I've used a combination of a custom Exec task and a python script to accomplish this.

import sys
import shutil
import zipfile

from pathlib import Path

clients = ["Client A", "Client B"]

for client in clients:
    Path("./published/" + client).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with zipfile.ZipFile("./build/libs/PROJECT-" + sys.argv[1] + ".jar", "r") as zipo:
        with zipfile.ZipFile("./published/" + client + "/PROJECT-" + sys.argv[1] + ".jar", "w") as zipf:
            zipf.comment = zipo.comment
            for item in zipo.infolist():
                if item.filename != "PROJECT.properties":
                    zipf.writestr(item, zipo.read(item.filename))
            zipf.writestr("PROJECT.properties", "client=" + client)

This code takes a single argument (the version number we are setting up) and creates copies of the jar for each client, removing the test properties file and writing a new one. Each client has a folder in a "published" directory at the root of the project with their customized version of the built jar.
(This snipped has been cleaned up and simplified a bit since it's actually used to package multiple projects at once, so there may be minor syntax errors.)
